# Java formatting GMT Date

Tags: java, date, calendar

I'm not finding a way to do edit GMT Date

I receive "params.date" one string in this format "yyyyMMdd", so this is my flow:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat('yyyyMMdd').parse(params.data)
System.out.println(sdf.parse(params.data))
```

output:

```
Thu Nov 17 21:00:00 GMT-03:00 2022
```

And I need it:

```
Thu Nov 17 21:00:00 GMT-00:00 2022
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: A `Date` itself doesn't have a format (other than a default format implemented in its `toString()` method, which use your default timezone). If you want a different format, you also need to use a formatter to *format* the date you want. As an aside, please stop using the legacy classes like `java.util.Date`, and switch to the better designed classes in `java.time`.

Comment: Your input is a _date_ not a date and a time. A date has no timezone. Why do you think `20221117` should mean nine o'clock in the evening on November 17?

Comment: @ThomasBehr I've in my database this data "2022-11-19T02:00:00.000+00:00" and it is considering the same as this "2022-11-18T23:59:00.000-03:00",

Comment: @GustavoSilvaCosta Ok, my question was meant to point you towards the fact that you specified your date format as `yyyyMMdd` which means there is information about the day, the month, and the year, but not about the time of the day. Of course, it does not work if your input data does not match the parse format.

Anyways, follow the advice given by MarkRotteveel and ArvindKumarAvinash: Use java.time.

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I can get for example `Fri Nov 18 00:00:00 GMT-03:00 2022`, but I can’t get 21:00:00 from the code you have shown. There must be something else going on that you haven’t posted yet. Please, if we’re to help, give us a [mre].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few important points:

1. Thu Nov 17 21:00:00 GMT-03:00 2022 is not equal to Thu Nov 17 21:00:00 GMT-00:00 2022. The date-time of Thu Nov 17 21:00:00 GMT-03:00 2022 is equal to the date-time of Fri Nov 18 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 2022 which you can obtain by adding 3 hours to Thu Nov 17 21:00:00 GMT-03:00 2022.
2. Your time-zone has an offset of -03:00 and therefore the `java.util.Date` object is being displayed with the default time-zone offset. Note that `java.util.Date` does not represent a real date-time, rather, it gives you the number of milliseconds from the Epoch and then the `Date#toString` implementation applies the system's time-zone to render the string.
3. The ***java.util*** date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

**Demo with java.time API**:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                String data = "20221118";
                LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(data, DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);

                ZonedDateTime zdt1 = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC);
                ZonedDateTime zdt2 = zdt1.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.of("-03:00"));

                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT'xxx uuuu",
                                Locale.ENGLISH);
                System.out.println(formatter.format(zdt2));
                System.out.println(formatter.format(zdt1));
        }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Thu Nov 17 21:00:00 GMT-03:00 2022
Fri Nov 18 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 2022
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.